Editing WhatsApp Message Template with Dropdown Menu - Issue with Request Body Structure
I'm trying to edit a WhatsApp message template that includes a dropdown menu. According to the documentation, I should be able to edit the template using a POST request to the WhatsApp Message Template endpoint. However, I'm unsure how to properly structure the request body to modify the dropdown options.
Here is the request body I've tried:
API = https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/{template_id}

{
    "components": [
        {
            "type": "HEADER",
            "format": "TEXT",
            "text": "Bot"
        },
        {
            "type": "BODY",
            "text": "What route do you want to consult? "
        },
        {
            "type": "BUTTONS",
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "type": "Form",
                    "name": "flow_path",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "type": "Dropdown",
                            "label": "Routes",
                            "required": true,
                            "name": "Dropdown_130982",
                            "data-source": [
                                {
                                    "id": "B101",
                                    "title": "B101"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "H20",
                                    "title": "H20"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "6",
                                    "title": "6"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "D81",
                                    "title": "D81"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "J24",
                                    "title": "J24"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextCaption",
                            "text": "Select the route you want to consult"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Footer",
                            "label": "Continue",
                            "on-click-action": {
                                "name": "complete",
                                "payload": {
                                    "screen_0_Dropdown_0": "${form.Dropdown_130982}"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

When I send this request, I receive an error. Can someone please provide guidance on the correct way to edit a dropdown in a WhatsApp message template?
Error:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Unexpected key \"name\" on param \"components[2]['buttons'][0]\".",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "AcGB-hPMI19J78vXMC8EQ5B"
    }
}

I have tried editing the flow directly, but it gives an error since it only allows editing drafts. I have tried editing without the buttons and it works, but with them, it gives an error. So, the problem is in how I send the JSON when editing the buttons, but I haven't found a guide on how to do it.
